# How to compare color variable to color upon button press?

Tags: android

I want the user to be awarded a point to their score counter if they click/tap the colored button corresponding to the color of the word displayed. Here's some of the code:

```
int[] androidColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
word.setTextColor(randomAndroidColor);
```

This shows how the random color to the string is applied. How could I make an a response to a button click, and how would I make that response be a comparison between the random string color (randomAndroidColor) and the button pressed? I'm aware how to add the point (score++), but not sure about what I requested above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the color (int) from a TextView using `TextView#getCurrentTextColor()`. You already use the colors from your array as ints, so it's a plain comparison (from Activity):

```
int[] randomColors = ... ;
int myColor = getRandomColor(randomColors);
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_id);
if (myColor == myTextView.getCurrentTextColor()) {
    // do your magic
}
```

Comment: Otherwise, it's a programming question. I could solve the problem for you, but where's the fun in that? :)

Comment: How could I compare the string (a color e.g: "Yellow") to the color of the button tapped? Sorry if I didn't make that clear in the question. E.g: "Yellow" (in random color) is displayed and yellow button is tapped (one more point), or "Red" (in random color) and blue button tapped (no response).

Comment: Oh that :) You would have to map it somehow (a Map or a SparseArray perhaps), a key-value pair structure where you would use your colors (integers) as keys and your Strings as values. Or the other way around, depending on how you want to compare them.